# QT build fails with NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'echo' : return code '0x1'

Tags: visual-studio, qt, compiler-errors, linker, cmake

I am using QT and CMake to build application for windows. When I run my CMakeLists.txt file I get the following warning:

```
CMake Warning at c:/Program Files/CMake 3.4/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/InstallRequiredSystemLibraries.cmake:343 (message):
  system runtime library file does not exist:
  'MSVC10_REDIST_DIR-NOTFOUND/x86/Microsoft.VC100.CRT/msvcp100.dll'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:165 (INCLUDE)

CMake Warning at c:/Program Files/CMake 3.4/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/InstallRequiredSystemLibraries.cmake:343 (message):
  system runtime library file does not exist:
  'MSVC10_REDIST_DIR-NOTFOUND/x86/Microsoft.VC100.CRT/msvcr100.dll'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:165 (INCLUDE)
```

I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676676/cant-install-msvcp100-dll) related to this warning but unlike the poster of that question I am not writing a GUI application. As I am new to using CMake I don't know how to make my linker flags correct. As this is just a warning in my CMake I can go ahead an finish the CMake anyway. The trouble is when I try to build my application I get the following compiler error:

```
CMake Error: No Script specified for argument -P
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'echo' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
12:02:32: The process "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project openfls (kit: Desktop)
When executing step 'Make'
```

What I am asking is how do the warning that I get when running my CMake leading to the compiler error? If so how do I resolve the warning (editing the flags)? If not is it important to address the warning (or can I just ignore it) and what should I be doing to prevent the compiler error?

Comment: Try updating your CMake to a recent version, that might help.

Comment: I tried updating CMake from 2.8 to 3.4 but it didn't make a difference. (I've updated the warning message above)

Comment: You have to tell where CMake can find the MSCV_redist_dir. I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my cmake error by identifying some linux specific includes which windows did not know what to do with (things relating to CPACK). This however did not resolve the errors I got when I tried to build, answering my question as to whether the two were related.

The problem when I was building is that QT is not properly set up to build on this system (the environmental variables for libraries ect. were not set). This had not been a problem before building on this machine as previously using qmake it had used the microsoft visual compiler. So to resolve my error I ran my cmake manually outside of QT then [opened the solution file](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/cmake-and-visual-studio/) in Visual C++.